# header and menu is missing from Login module page--user--login.tpl.php

Tags: theming, users, hooks

I am implementing Custom Login module but Header is missing...

My Directory is :

```
modules
  |
  --- module_name
          |
          --- css  
          |
          --- module_name.info
          |
          --- module_name.module
          |
          --- templates
```

module_name.module contains :

```
function module_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
        $form['name']['#attributes']['autofocus'] = 'autofocus';
        $form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Email');
        $form['pass']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Password');
        // We don't really need descriptions to tell us what we already know...
        unset($form['name']['#description']);
        unset($form['pass']['#description']);

        // $form['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/css/login.css';
    }

    // We don't want to change page titles on other pages.
    // Array of arg(1) url values on target pages.
    $pages = array('login', 'password');
    if (!in_array(arg(1), $pages)) {
        return;
    }

    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'user_login':
            drupal_set_title(t('Login'));
            break;

        case 'user_pass':
            drupal_set_title(t('Forgot your password?'));
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function module_name_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
    $mod_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name');

    $theme_registry_copy = $theme_registry;
    _theme_process_registry($theme_registry_copy, 'phptemplate', 'theme_engine', '', $mod_path);
    $theme_registry += array_diff_key($theme_registry_copy, $theme_registry);

    $hooks = array('page');
    foreach ($hooks as $h) {
        if (!isset($theme_registry[$h]['theme paths'])) {
            $theme_registry[$h]['theme paths'] = array();
        }

        _module_name_insert_after_first_element($theme_registry[$h]['theme paths'], $mod_path);
    }
}

/**
 * Function responsible for inserting a new element after the first one.
 */
function _module_name_insert_after_first_element(&$a, $element) {
    if (is_array($a)) {
        $first_element = array_shift($a);
        if ($first_element) {
            array_unshift($a, $first_element, $element);
        }
        else {
            array_unshift($a, $element);
        }
    }
}
```

templates/page--user--login.tpl.php contains:

```
<div  class="login">

  <div id="middle_part">
    <h2 class="title"><?php print $title; ?></h2>

    <?php print $messages; ?>
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
</div>
  </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Everything is ok, but Header and Menu is missing (as defined in my current theme) from HTML output (/user/login), any suggestion?

Comment: Compare your page--user--login.tpl.php to the standard page.tpl.php in your theme/parent theme and you'll probably see its missing other variables like $page['header'] or something like that. So you'll need to incorporate those into this other page template

Comment: @LeighMason Thanks, means that i need to copy `page.tpl.php` to my `page--user--login.tpl.php` OR any way to include `page.tpl.php`  file

Comment: Yes ideally whenever you're creating a new template you should copy of existing template being used and then alter that copy so it keeps all the original content. So you will probably be best deleting your page--user--login.tpl.php, creating a new version of that by copying page.tpl.php and then add any changes into it

Comment: @LeighMason Thank you for replying,  is there any way to do without theme dependency, like if i will change theme in future then it will automatically take new theme `region` or `header` ??

Answer (score 1):

Your page--user--login.tpl.php is overriding the page.tpl.php. Print your header & menus regions/variables  in the file 'page--user--login.tpl.php'.